# Solving $f(n,m)=(2n-m)f(n-1,m-1)+f(n-1,m)$ without combinatorial proof

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

How to solve the 2d recurrence
$$
\begin{align}
f(n,0)&=1[n \geq 0]\\
f(0,m)&=1[m=0]\\
f(n,m)&=(2n-m)f(n-1,m-1)+f(n-1,m) \tag{$n\geq1,m\geq1 $}
\end{align}
$$
I know the answer is
$$
f(n,m)=\binom{n}{m}^2m!
$$
But it comes from combinatorics and the solution I knew was based on mysterious bijection. The answer equals the number of ways to place $m$ ball in a $n\times n$ chessboard, satisfying they are in separate columns and rows. But I got this recurrence in another completely different problem.

Is there a straightforward method to solve the recurrence, without knowing the answer in advance? I tried using generating functions, but I failed.

Comment: A glance at the recurrence formula shows that for fixed $m$, $f(.,m)$ is a polynomial in $n$. Computing this polynomial for a few small values of $m$ and factorizing them, we guess the general answer. So all that needs to be shown is that $\binom{n}{m}^2m!$ does indeed satisfy the recurrence formula. And this is not very hard.

Comment: Some initial conditions are missing, for example the recurrence is not enough to determine $f(0,1)$.

Comment: @Sil You are right, I edited with the missing base cases.